# Por que se ejecuta el default del switch independientemente del valor?

Tags: javascript

En esta funcion para calcular el IMC, independientemente del valor que ingrese, se ejecuta el "default" y no logro ver el error. Probe con decimales y sin decimales y aparece lo mismo.

```
 var altura = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu altura"));
var peso = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu peso"));

function calcularIMC (altura,peso){
  return peso/altura**2;
} 

var imc = calcularIMC(altura,peso);

switch(imc){
  case (imc<=18.5):
    alert("Bajo peso");
    break;

  case ((imc>=18.5) && (imc<=24.9)):
    alert("Peso normal");
    break;

  case ((imc>=25) && (imc<=29.9)):
    alert("Peso sobrepeso");
    break;

  default: 
    alert("Obesidad");
    break;

}
```

Comment: solo debes cambiar el `switch(imc){` por `switch(true){` y eso deberia solventar tu problema!

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

el error se da porque [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) toma la expresion que se le pase y la compara con el `case` y tu caso ninguna va  concidir ya que estas usando otra expresion en el case la forma mas simple de solventar esto es pasar `true` para que evalue el valor de case y si es true coincida `true == true`

ejemplo:

```js
 var altura = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu altura"));
var peso = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu peso"));

function calcularIMC (altura,peso){
  return peso/altura**2;
} 

var imc = calcularIMC(altura,peso);

switch(true){
  case (imc<=18.5):
    alert("Bajo peso");
    break;

  case ((imc>=18.5) && (imc<=24.9)):
    alert("Peso normal");
    break;

  case ((imc>=25) && (imc<=29.9)):
    alert("Peso sobrepeso");
    break;

  default: 
    alert("Obesidad");
    break;

}
```

Comment: Pero ¿no es una aberración eso de `switch(true)`? ¿No debería cambiarse toda la estructura  `switch()` por una serie de `if .. else if ... else`? ¿O es práctica común lo de `switch(true)` en el mundo javascript?

Comment: @abulafia if.elseif...else deberia ser la mejor solucion para tratar el problema pero tampoco es tan descabellado utilizar `switch(true)`

Answer (score 3):

En JavaScript se puede utilizar el `switch(true)` y luego evaluar cada condición en el case.

En este caso, que son unos *"casos predefinidos"* la estructura de `if ... else if ... else` es otra opción, ya que son también pocos casos.

En el caso de que fuesen muchos casos, por legibilidad yo utilizaría la estructura del `switch(true) ... case`.

Ejemplo usando una estructura`if ... else if ... else`:

```js
var altura = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu altura"));
var peso = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa tu peso"));

function calcularIMC (altura,peso){
  return peso/altura**2;
} 

var imc = calcularIMC(altura,peso);

if(imc<=18.5){
  alert("Bajo peso");
}else if (imc <=24.9){
  alert("Peso normal");
}else if (imc<29.9){
  alert("Peso sobrepeso");
}else{
  alert("Obesidad");
}
```